# Authorization Required for Salesforce site

Tags: salesforce

i am newbie in salesforce.i created a site in salesforce and facing a message Authorization Required.i want to make my site public what general approach should i follow to make my site public? please provide some relevant content or link!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get it what you meant by `site` above. Are you referring to your Salesforce.com *account* as `site` or did you create a *Force.com Site*?

For the former case: Salesforce.com is based on B2B model. For every user to get access, you have to create a user in Salesforce.com, and every user costs you a license fee (the developer org allows creation of only 2 users). Simply speaking you cannot just make your Salesforce.com account publicly accessible to everyone.

For the latter case: Salesforce.com allows other ways of making a public website -- Force.com Sites. You can find introduction to Force.com Sites at http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Sites of jump directly to creating a Force.com Site by following instructions at http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites.

If you are finding difficulty in accessing Force.com Site, then you probably might not have given proper access rights to the resources used in the Visualforce Page used for the Force.com Site.

Comment: thanks solved it!! but one more point if u didn't add any visualforce page in Force.com site then also u have to face Authorization Required